# jmeter dependancy on internet connection->performance testing

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter for tesing a website. My question is that is jmeter dependant on the internet connection? What if there is no internet connection? Will jmeter be able to send requests?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Jmeter locally, yes -- the overall load capacity of your test is entirely dependent on your Last Mile connection. But if you don't want to fork out the $$$ for your own OC-3, you can look to hosted Jmeter solutions providers -- basically Jmeter as a Service.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter just captures the web requests and mimics the behavior, helping you automate the requests. As you are simulating web requests, you need connectivity to your web application. If you have your website hosted locally in that case you don't need internet connection, but you will surely need a way to reach the website wiz. LAN.

Again the results will vary based on the network bandwith, latency etc. If there is no internet connection and if your browser is not able to make request to your site, then JMeter will also not be able to reach the site and won't be able to make request.